# trim text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my case i have a lot of text like this :

```
(name price currency * quantity)

Blue Book 5 $ * 100

Green Books 34 Uk * 50
```

and ...

this my html and jQuery code.

```js
    jQuery('td.quantity_col dd.variation- p').text(function(_, curr) {  
        //jQuery('p.time').text('Time of match')
      return  curr.split('*').pop().trim();      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="woocommerce">

    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass quantity_col">
            <dl class="variation">
                    <dd class="variation-"><p class="time">Blue Book 5 $ * 100</p></dd>   
            </dl>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass quantity_col">
            <dl class="variation">
                    <dd class="variation-"><p>green Books 34 Uk * 50</p></dd> 
            </dl>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i want to trim text like bellow:

```
Blue Book 5 $ * 100  --->  Blue Book

Green Books 34 Uk * 50 ---> Green Books
```

any solution with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but I have to say your code is messy. You should clean it a bit before trying to interact with the DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td.quantity_col dl dd.variation- p').each(function(i,x) {  
    if (i%3 == 1) {
      console.log($(this).text().split(/\d/)[0].trim())
      $(this).text($(this).text().split(/\d/)[0].trim())
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="woocommerce">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#1</td>
        <td class="tdclass"><span class="other_item">wallet</span></td>
        <td class="tdclass">$45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#2</td>
        <td class="tdclass quantity_col">
            <dl class="variation">
                <dt class="variation-">Select Category :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p>Category 1</p></dd>
                <dt class="variation-">Select Product :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p class="time">Blue Book 5 $ * 100</p></dd>
                <dt class="variation-">Link :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p></dd>      
            </dl>
            <span class="other_item">wallet2</span>
        </td>
        <td class="tdclass">$35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#2</td>
        <td class="tdclass quantity_col">
            <dl class="variation">
                <dt class="variation-">Select Category :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p>Category 1</p></dd>
                <dt class="variation-">Select Product :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p>green Books 34 Uk * 50</p></dd>
                <dt class="variation-">Link :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p></dd>      
            </dl>
            <span class="other_item">wallet2</span>
        </td>
        <td class="tdclass">$35</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

There should be a way to do this ith proper CSS selectors, but seing your DOM is messy, I didn't check for a CSS solution.

Comment: thank you. I updated the HTML code. your code dosn't work out of console log.

Comment: Take what I wrote to catch what you want and put it where you want. Sorry I won't code your app for you, your question was how to get a particular element. There you have.

Comment: your solution is work well in console log. but I'm confused how to use it to trim text in html code. can you help me?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Replace the text you have in HTML code with the same text trimmed?

Comment: @ djcaesar9114 yes i want to replace the trimmed text with the original text.

Comment: Check the line I added